# Как проверить, использует ли Windows trim на конкретном диске?

Tags: windows, windows-10, железо, ssd

Команда

```
fsutil behavior query disabledeletenotify
```

показывает по файловым системам

[image: скриншот fsutil behavior query disabledeletenotify]

т. е. у меня всё включено.

А как посмотреть по конкретному диску? Нашёл рекомендацию в CrystalDiskInfo смотреть, поддерживает ли диск trim.

[image: скриншот CrystalDiskInfo]

Он считает, что поддерживает, но сомнения возникают из-за того, что он - единственная программа, которая смогла увидеть SMART и температуру диска. В Hard Disk Sentinel всё пусто, в Speccy - тоже. Виндоусовская оптимизация дисков в курсе, что диск - это ссд.

Ссд подключено через USB-корпус. В системе определяется как `Realtek RTL9210B-CG SCSI Disk Device (SSD)`, хотя на самом деле является `Samsung 970 EVO Plus`. Samsung Magician его по usb не узнаёт:

[image: скриншот Samsung Magician]

Comment: А разве trim не делается средствами самого контроллера ссд? И трим средствами ОС - старый костыль для старых ссд с более простым контроллером?

Comment: @donRumata, что именно должно делаться средствами самого ссд? Конкретно стирание ячеек - вероятно да. Но ведь кто-то должен предварительно сказать ему, что они свободные. Вряд ли контроллер ссд сам знает, как оно разбито на разделы, какая файловая система у этих разделов и какое пространство в этой файловой системе - мусор, а какое - полезные данные.

Comment: Ну минимум в саму ссд приходит комманда от ОС о том, что "надо удалить вот этот файл", т.е. пометить вот этот блок и вон тот как пустые. Сильно сомневаюсь, что этих комманд для всех известных ФС на столько много, что их невозможно запомнить во внутреннем чипе ссд.

Comment: @donRumata, "файл"? Ссд знает о файлах? Или только о секторах? Когда на hdd удаляется файл, то стирается только информация о файле, а содержимое остаётся и его файл ещё можно достать. В случае ссд оно должно как-то узнать, какие именно сектора принадлежали файлу, поэтому их можно будет затереть при необходимости. Я думал, это и есть та самая команда trim - сообщить диску, какие сектора стали свободны. Или я неправильно понимаю?

Comment: Насколько я понял из гугла, TRIM периодически выполняется планировщиком заданий через команду вроде `defrag /L`. Возможно, в «Просмотре событий» - «Журналы Windows» - «Приложения» есть что-нибудь интересное от источника Defrag? (К сожалению, не имею USB-контроллеров с поддержкой TRIM, не могу сам проверить)

Comment: @andreymal, а если его явно вызвать?

Comment: Я не говорил про то, что ссд знает про файлы. Я предположил, что контроллер имеет техническую возможность перехватывать команды на удаление и опираясь на них уже делать свою логику. Мы пытались восстановить тока что удалённые файлы и разделы со свежей ссд в качестве эксперемента. Не получилось вообще ничего. Ни квикскан, ни дипскан не показали даже обрывков файлов и разделов. Из чего я сделал вывод, который написал выше.

Comment: @donRumata, с системного ссд (sata) я файлы восстановить могу, причём, непонятно, насколько давно удалённые (только что восстановил манифест одной из прошлых версий аваст-браузера: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVdnR.png & https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK2WT.png). В любом случае, я не понял твою идею. Потереть (или хотя бы пометить свободными) кластеры файлов может только кто-то, кто знает файловую систему. Кто это по твоей версии?

Comment: Тогда я хз. Надо читать прям спеки.